# Conditionally map keys depending on the application being used

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

Here is my need on keyboard mapping:

- When using Terminal, exchange the use of <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd> (map one to the other)
- Otherwise, restore the default mapping on these two keys

How to achieve this?

Comment: You could do this with something like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) like this with Karabiner:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>TERMINAL</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>onlyterminal</name>
    <identifier>onlyterminal</identifier>
    <only>TERMINAL</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```